# Responsive Periodic Table of Elements in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

Lately, I've been studying a lot about responsive design in HTML/CSS and decided to try to code the periodic table of elements in HTML/CSS in order to practice. I have the basic structure of the table (Using mostly `div` elements) but I'm majorly lacking a responsive flow. I've tried using % and it's still being stubborn. Any nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

**HTML:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <title> Periodic Table of Elements, in CSS! </title> 
    </head> 
    <body>
        <section>
            <div id="container">
            <div id="panelOne">
                <div class="box"> H </div> 
                <div class="box"> Li </div> 
                <div class="box"> Na </div> 
                <div class="box"> K </div> 
                <div class="box"> Rb </div> 
                <div class="box"> Cs </div> 
                <div class="box"> Fr </div> 
            </div>
            <div id="panelTwo">
                <div class="box"> Be </div> 
                <div class="box"> Mg </div> 
                <div class="box"> Ca </div> 
                <div class="box"> Sr </div> 
                <div class="box"> Ba </div> 
                <div class="box"> Ra </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="panelThree">
                <div class="box"> Sc </div> 
                <div class="box"> Y </div> 
                <div class="box"> X </div> 
                <div class="box"> X </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="panelThree">
                <div class="box"> Ti </div> 
                <div class="box"> Zr </div> 
                <div class="box"> Hf </div> 
                <div class="box"> Rf </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="panelThree">
                <div class="box"> V </div> 
                <div class="box"> Nb </div> 
                <div class="box"> Ta </div> 
                <div class="box"> Db </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="panelThree">
                <div class="box"> Cr </div> 
                <div class="box"> Mo </div> 
                <div class="box"> W </div> 
                <div class="box"> Sg </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="panelThree">
                <div class="box"> Mn </div> 
                <div class="box"> Tc </div> 
                <div class="box"> Re </div> 
                <div class="box"> Bh </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="panelThree">
                <div class="box"> Fe </div> 
                <div class="box"> Ru </div> 
                <div class="box"> Os </div> 
                <div class="box"> Hs </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="panelThree">
                <div class="box"> Co </div> 
                <div class="box"> Rh</div> 
                <div class="box"> Ir </div> 
                <div class="box"> Mt </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="panelThree">
                <div class="box"> Ni </div> 
                <div class="box"> Pd </div> 
                <div class="box"> Pt </div> 
                <div class="box"> Ds </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="panelThree">
                <div class="box"> Cu </div> 
                <div class="box">Ag </div> 
                <div class="box"> Au </div> 
                <div class="box"> Rg </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="panelThree">
                <div class="box"> Zn </div> 
                <div class="box"> Cd </div> 
                <div class="box"> Hg </div> 
                <div class="box"> Cn </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="panelFour">
                <div class="box"> B </div> 
                <div class="box"> Al </div> 
                <div class="box"> Ga </div> 
                <div class="box"> In </div> 
                <div class="box"> Ti </div> 
                <div class="box"> Uut </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="panelFour">
                <div class="box"> C </div> 
                <div class="box"> Si </div> 
                <div class="box"> Ge </div> 
                <div class="box"> Sn </div>
                <div class="box"> Rb </div> 
                <div class="box"> Fl </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="panelFour">
                <div class="box">N </div> 
                <div class="box">P </div> 
                <div class="box">As </div> 
                <div class="box">Sb </div> 
                <div class="box"> Bi </div> 
                <div class="box"> Uup </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="panelFour">
                <div class="box"> O </div> 
                <div class="box"> S </div> 
                <div class="box"> Se </div> 
                <div class="box"> Te </div> 
                <div class="box"> Po </div> 
                <div class="box"> Lv </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="panelFour">
                <div class="box"> F </div> 
                <div class="box"> Cl </div> 
                <div class="box"> Br </div> 
                <div class="box"> I </div> 
                <div class="box"> At </div> 
                <div class="box"> Uus </div> 
            </div>
            <div id="panelFive">
                <div class="box"> He </div> 
                <div class="box"> Ne </div> 
                <div class="box"> Ar </div> 
                <div class="box"> Kr </div> 
                <div class="box"> Xe </div> 
                <div class="box"> Rn </div> 
                <div class="box"> Uuo </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="lowerContainer">
            <div class="bottom">
                <div class="box"> La </div> 
                <div class="box"> Ac </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
                <div class="box"> La </div> 
                <div class="box"> Ac </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
                <div class="box"> La </div> 
                <div class="box"> Ac </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
                <div class="box"> La </div> 
                <div class="box"> Ac </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
                <div class="box"> La </div> 
                <div class="box"> Ac </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
                <div class="box"> La </div> 
                <div class="box"> Ac </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
                <div class="box"> La </div> 
                <div class="box"> Ac </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
                <div class="box"> La </div> 
                <div class="box"> Ac </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
                <div class="box"> La </div> 
                <div class="box"> Ac </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
                <div class="box"> La </div> 
                <div class="box"> Ac </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
                <div class="box"> La </div> 
                <div class="box"> Ac </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
                <div class="box"> La </div> 
                <div class="box"> Ac </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
                <div class="box"> La </div> 
                <div class="box"> Ac </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
                <div class="box"> La </div> 
                <div class="box"> Ac </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
                <div class="box"> La </div> 
                <div class="box"> Ac </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
    body{
    font-size: 16px;
}
section{
    width: 1500px;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
#container{
    width: 1400px;
}
.box{
    border: 3px solid black; 
    max-width: 50px;
    max-height: 50px; 
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 50px; 
    text-align: center; 
    font-size: 1.63em;
}

#panelOne{
    float: left; 
}

#panelTwo{
    float: left; 
    position: relative; 
    top: 75px; 
}

.panelThree{
    float: left; 
    position: relative; 
    top: 225px; 
}

.panelFour{
    float: left; 
    position: relative; 
    top: 75px; 
}

#panelFive{
    float: left; 
}

#lowerContainer{
    float: right; 
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.bottom{
    float: left; 
}
```

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cqkAd/

Comment: Are you trying to get each box element to shrink as the page shrinks?

Comment: A responsive periodic table wouldn't make much sense, what you're looking for is a fluid layout (percent based sizing)

Comment: @Pier-LucGendreau Yes that's what I'm going for. Sorry I had the vocabulary mixed up. Here's the updated jsfiddle thus far. http://jsfiddle.net/WEuB6/

Comment: To get the boxes to shrink properly you will have to take off the 50px line height and use a percentage based padding on the boxes.

Comment: Why are you not using a `<table>` for tabular data?

Comment: For anyone who is interested, here is my final version of this. Thanks for helping me through it!
http://jsfiddle.net/KjgfV/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using mostly all of your suggestions, I was able to re-create my own fluid layout and I"m pretty happy with the results. Thanks for all your help! Here's the code.

http://jsfiddle.net/KjgfV/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Periodic Table of Elements, in CSS! </title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> <!--Main StyleSheet -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> <!-- Google Fonts --> 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- jQUery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>
    <section>
    <div id="menu"> The Periodic Table of Elements </div> 
        <div id="container">
        <div id="panelOne">
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen"> H </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium"> Li </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium"> Na </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium"> K </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubidium"> Rb </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesium"> Cs </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francium"> Fr </a></div> 
        </div>
        <div id="panelTwo">
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beryllium"> Be </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnesium"> Mg </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium"> Ca</a> </div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strontium"> Sr </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barium"> Ba </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radium"> Ra </a></div> 
        </div>
        <div id="panelThree">
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scandium"> Sc</a> </div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yttrium"> Y </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="#"> * </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="#"> * </a></div> 
        </div>
        <div id="panelThree">
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titanium"> Ti </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zirconium"> Zr </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hafnium"> Hf </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rutherfordium"> Rf </a></div> 
        </div>
        <div id="panelThree">
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanadium"> V </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niobium"> Nb </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tantalum"> Ta </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dubnium"> Db </a></div> 
        </div>
        <div id="panelThree">
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium"> Cr </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molybdenum"> Mo </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tungsten"> W</a> </div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seaborgium"> Sg</a> </div> 
        </div>
        <div id="panelThree">
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manganese"> Mn</a> </div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technetium"> Tc </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhenium"> Re </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohrium"> Bh </a></div> 
        </div>
        <div id="panelThree">
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron"> Fe </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruthenium"> Ru </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmium"> Os </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hassium"> Hs </a></div> 
        </div>
        <div id="panelThree">
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobalt"> Co </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhodium"> Rh</a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iridium"> Ir</a> </div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meitnerium"> Mt </a></div> 
        </div>
        <div id="panelThree">
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nickel"> Ni </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palladium"> Pd </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platinum"> Pt </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darmstadtium"> Ds </a></div> 
        </div>
        <div id="panelThree">
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper"> Cu</a> </div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver">Ag </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold"> Au</a> </div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roentgenium"> Rg</a> </div> 
        </div>
        <div id="panelThree">
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zinc"> Zn</a> </div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadmium"> Cd</a> </div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury"> Hg</a> </div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copernicium"> Cn</a> </div> 
        </div>
        <div id="panelTwo">
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boron"> B </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium"> Al</a> </div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallium"> Ga</a> </div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indium"> In </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thallium"> Ti </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ununtrium"> Uut </a></div> 
        </div>
        <div id="panelTwo">
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon"> C</a> </div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon"> Si</a> </div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanium"> Ge</a> </div> 
            <div class="box"> <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tin">Sn</a> </div>
            <div class="box"> <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead">Rb</a> </div> 
            <div class="box"> <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flerovium">Fl</a> </div>  
        </div>
        <div id="panelTwo">
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen">N </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphorus">P </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arsenic">As</a> </div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimony">Sb </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bismuth"> Bi</a> </div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ununpentium"> Uup</a> </div> 
        </div>
        <div id="panelTwo">
            <div class="box"> <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen">O</a> </div> 
            <div class="box"> <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfur">S </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium"> Se</a> </div> 
            <div class="box"> <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tellurium">Te</a> </div> 
            <div class="box"> <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polonium">Po </a></div> 
            <div class="box"> <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Livermorium">Lv </a></div> 
        </div>
        <div id="panelTwo">
            <div class="box"> <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorine">F </a></div> 
            <div class="box"> <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorine">Cl</a> </div> 
            <div class="box"> <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bromine">Br</a> </div> 
            <div class="box"> <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iodine">I </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astatine"> At </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ununseptrium"> Uus</a> </div> 
        </div>
        <div id="panelOne">
            <div class="box"> <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium">He </a></div> 
            <div class="box"> <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neon">Ne</a> </div> 
            <div class="box"> <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon">Ar </a></div> 
            <div class="box"> <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krypton">Kr </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenon"> Xe </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon"> Rn </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ununoctium"> Uuo </a></div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="clear"></div>
    <div id="lowerContainer">
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanthanum"> La </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actinium"> Ac </a></div> 
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cerium"> Ce </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorium"> Th </a></div> 
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Praseodymium"> Pr </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protactinium"> Pa </a></div> 
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neodymium"> Nd</a> </div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranium"> U </a></div> 
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promethium"> Pm </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neptunium"> Np </a></div> 
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samarium"> Sm </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plutonium"> Pu </a></div> 
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europium"> Eu </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americium"> Am </a></div> 
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gadolinium"> Gd </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curium"> Cm </a></div> 
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terbium"> Tb</a> </div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkelium"> Bk</a> </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dysprosium"> Dy </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Californium"> Cf </a></div> 
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="box"> <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holmium">Ho </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einsteinium"> Es</a> </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erbium"> Er </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermium"> Fm</a> </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thulium"> Tm </a></div> 
            <div class="box"> <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mendelevium">Md </a></div> 
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ytterbium"> Yb </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nobelium"> No</a> </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lutetium"> Lu</a> </div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawrencium"> Lr</a> </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="infoContainer">
            This is the information. 
    </div> 
    </section>  
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
}
body{
    background-image: url("bg.png"); 
}
#menu{
    width: 400px; 
    margin: 0px auto; 
    webkit-text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000; 
    moz-text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000; 
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000; 
    font-size: 40px;
}

section {
    max-width: 1064px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-width: 300px;
}

#infoContainer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 43%;
    width: 500px;
    top: 78px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -250px;
}

#container {
width: 100%;
}

#container:before,
#container:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
#container:after {
    clear:both;
}
/* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
#container {
    zoom:1;
}

.box{
    border: 1px solid black; 
    padding: 20%;
    text-align: center; 
    font-size: 1.63em;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 3px; 
    border-radius: 3px; 
    margin: 2px; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ccc; 
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ccc; 
    box-shadow: 1.5px 2px 2px #000; 
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ccc; 
}

.box a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit; 
}

.box:hover{
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ccc; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}

#panelOne{
    float: left; 
    width: 5.5556%;
}

#panelTwo{
    float: left; 
    width: 5.5556%;
    margin-top: 6%; 
}

#panelThree{
    float: left; 
    width: 5.5556%;
    margin-top: 18%;
}

#lowerContainer{
    float: right; 
    margin-top:1%;
    width: 80%; 
}

.bottom{
    float: left; 
    width: 6.66666667%; 
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px){
    #panelTwo{
        margin-top: 6.3%;
    }

    #panelThree{
        margin-top: 18.9%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px){
    #panelTwo{
        margin-top: 6.8%;
    }

    #panelThree{
        margin-top: 20.5%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
    .box{
        font-size: 1em; 
    }

    #panelTwo{
        margin-top: 5.7%;
    }

    #panelThree{
        margin-top: 17%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px){

    #panelTwo{
        margin-top: 6.2%;
    }

    #panelThree{
        margin-top: 19%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 550px){
    .box{
        font-size: .5em; 
    }
        #panelTwo{
        margin-top: 5.5%;
    }

    #panelThree{
        margin-top: 15.8%;
    }
    #menu{
        width: 300px; 
        font-size: 28px;
    }
    #infoContainer {
        top: 50px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px){
        #panelTwo{
        margin-top: 7.3%;
    }

    #panelThree{
        margin-top: 21.6%;
    }
}

#clear{
    clear: both; 
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var $ic = $('#infoContainer');
$ic.hide();
$('.box').click(function () {
    var newLink = $(this).find('a').attr('href'); 
    var left  = ($(window).width()/2)-(600/2),
        top   = ($(window).height()/2)-(400/2),
        popup = window.open (newLink, "Element", "width=600, height=400, top="+top+", left="+left);
    return false;
}); //End box click
```

}); //End ready

Answer (score 2):

I have built a pure-css solution for you **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/UgEEg/)**. I got rid of the floats and unnecessary classes, set negative margins on each column to remove the 'double border' effect, used percentage padding to control box height, and removed unnecessary class names (though you can put them back, if you wish). There will be a small margin on the right, which can be removed with a negative margin if you like. Also, I set a minimum width on the table, which can be easily removed. It works in Crome - haven't tested it in other browsers. Let me know if you have any questions. Enjoy!

See the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UgEEg/) for the HTML markup. Here is the CSS:

```
#periodic_table {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 600px;
}

#periodic_table > div {
    margin-bottom: 2.5%;
}

#periodic_table > div > div {
    width: 5.5%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -7px;
}

#periodic_table > div > div > div {
    border: 3px solid black;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    background: red;
    margin-top: -3px;
    padding: 20% 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the boxes the get smaller then you need to make the width of your panel# classes have % width.

Comment: Thanks for the response(including the Media Queries one earlier). I've updated it with your suggestions. It's coming along! Thanks! 
http://jsfiddle.net/WEuB6/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use percent based widths like so:

```
#container{
    width: 100%;
}
.box{
    border: 3px solid black; 
    max-width: 50px;
    max-height: 50px; 
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 50px; 
    text-align: center; 
    font-size: 1.63em;
}
.panel{
    /* 100% divided by number of vertical panels */
    width: 5.5%;
}
```

Here's a fiddle with slightly tweaked HTML and full CSS:

http://jsfiddle.net/cqkAd/1/

It gets ugly at lower widths so you will want to add a fixed `min-width` (in px) and adjusting `padding` will help too.

As a side note, don't use spaces for padding and be consistent in your use of `id` and `class`.